# Volume-preserving diffeomorphism group of ball $\mathbb{D}^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\mathbb{D}^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |x| \leq 1 \}$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $ \omega$ be the usual volume-form on $\mathbb{D}^n$ inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is the group of volume preserving diffeomorphisms  $\mathrm{Diff}_\omega (\mathbb{D}^n)$ which is defined as $\mathrm{Diff}_\omega (\mathbb{D}^n) = \{ \phi \in \mathrm{Diff} (\mathbb{D}^n): \phi ^\ast \omega = \omega \}$, where $\mathrm{Diff} (\mathbb{D}^n)$ is the
diffeomorphism group of $\mathbb{D}^n$? I am specially interested in the component of the identity in this group.

There is a literature on the field of volume preserving diffeomorphisms groups $\mathrm{Diff}_\omega (M)$, where $M$ is a Riemanian manifold, among of them I can mention the book by Banyaga (It seems that some people uses the notation $\mathrm{SDiff} (M)$). But I am not able to find results in the special case of $M= \mathbb{D}^n$. Any reference is greatly admired.

Comment: I don't think there is an elementary description of that group. I think its homotopy groups are known, but that should be in Banyaga's book.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to find anything that is especially about $\mathrm{Diff}_\omega (\mathbb{D}^n)$ in Banyaga's book. @BenMcKay

Comment: Do you care about it as a topological group or a discrete group?

Comment: Definitely I'm interested to study volume-preserving diffeomorphisms which are close enough to the identity (in an appropriate sense), and not the whole machinery of the group. I don't know about the topology of his group, but it seems that topological group is much better! @skupers